# ::before pseudo element not displaying until I add display block/inline-block

Tags: css, display, pseudo-element

I have to add an SVG icon before each list item, I am trying to add SVG using `background-image`, however, the pseudo-element doesn't appear until I add display: block/inline-block. I didn't really understand this behavior here. Even adding display: inline doesn't render the icon.

Here's the code:

```
&::before {
  content: "";
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-image: url(./../img/SVG/chevron-thin-right.svg);
}
```

Comment: So you're just trying to understand why you need to use `display: block`?

Comment: @kpie yes, I am trying to understand why display: block works and display:inline doesn't display the svg icon in my case. Fairly new to the CSS world

Comment: I mean I hate to be this opaque but you need to use `display: block` because that's what works. Just remember `inline` does not allow you to set width and height, `block` does.